# org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.unset(Ljava/lang/String;)V on runnning an aggregate function in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

Hadoop version is 1.2.1 and Hive version is 1.0.1. Gone through the jars and have found unset function in `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf`

Why does still the error come when fired a query for example:

```
select count(*) from table;
```

Comment: Can u be more clear whats the error..?

Comment: Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.unset(Ljava/lang/String;)V

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec

Comment: The above msg gets displayed on hive console when an aggregate function is run.